# Can't import fl.motion

Tags: actionscript-3

I have Flex Builder 3 and currently writing an Actionscript 3  program.
I attempted to import fl.motion package in my program and it could not be found when I ran it.  This is the first time I am importing the fl.motion.  Is that package available to FlexBuilder 3 users.

Comment: if your'e trying to use the Flash Professional tween engine, you should use Tweener instead.  http://code.google.com/p/tweener/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you regularly own a FlashProfessional licence you can simply grab the the swc inside your Application folder. On Mac you might find it in `/Common/Configuration/Actionscript 3.0/libs/flash.swc`. Simply add the swc to your project references.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Flash Professional in order to use fl.motion.* packages.

It is not part of Flex or the standard Flash library. It only comes with Flash Professional.

It is still possible to get these packages one way or another, but I think there may be some legal issues if you do not have Flash Pro in the first place.

Of course, if you have Flash Pro, you can use these libraries in Flash Builder.

If it is in order to move objects, there are some free or open source tween libraries available on the web, like Tween Max.

Comment: TweenLite has license fees if you're selling your work (ie: Android App).  Tweener, in my opinion, is just as good, is the basis of TweenLite, and it's free.